# How do I do Indian-style (lahk, crore) thousand separators in Java?

Tags: java

Input value

```
double value = 668260.10;
```

Output should be: `6,68,260.10`.

I tried the below, but its doing `668,260.10` instead:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(loc);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
df.applyPattern("#,##,###.00");
String output = df.format(value);
System.out.println(output);
```

(Note: The separator style is as described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system).)

Comment: What's the input then? [ask], [mcve]

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that kind of formatting is fairly common in India and the surrounding countries.  I have no idea why.

Comment: if we do thousand separator in MS Excel for 668260.10 the we will get the separated value as  6,68,260.10 . so we need same as MS thousand separator.

Comment: it is [Lakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh)

Comment: @DavidWallace: [Sure enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system), though the article lacks citations. (Got there from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping.)

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormat` doesn't support this kind of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define custom formating like below

```
 public class Test {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##,##0.00");


            System.out.println(formatLakh(668260.10));
        }

        private static String formatLakh(double d) {
            String s = String.format(Locale.UK, "%1.2f", Math.abs(d));
            s = s.replaceAll("(.+)(...\\...)", "$1,$2");
            while (s.matches("\\d{3,},.+")) {
                s = s.replaceAll("(\\d+)(\\d{2},.+)", "$1,$2");
            }
            return d < 0 ? ("-" + s) : s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its working thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. Thanks. After that customization according to our needs also possible.